# What benefit would you get out of using cURL over Fiddler?

Tags: curl, fiddler

I am very familiar with Fiddler but haven't used cURL and was wondering if anyone can point to a specific advantage to using cURL over fiddler to test web requests.

Comment: Fiddler is an investigative tool for viewing and observing requests. cURL (to my understanding) makes the requests. I'm pretty sure they're Apples and Oranges to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CURL and Fiddler are quite different. cURL is purely a command line tool, and it runs on Mac and Linux as well as Windows.

Fiddler is a GUI-based tool that can be automated and debug traffic *from* Mac/Linux only when it's running on Windows and those clients are pointed at Fiddler.